# Android Service+ counter not working

Tags: java, android, service, counter

I am building an app that can counting the screen on time. First i build a service to send the count up timer values like 00:00  to `MainActivity` and here is my service implementation

```
public class MyService extends Service {


String time;
Intent io;




@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    try{

        PowerManager power=(PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn=power.isScreenOn();
            while(isScreenOn){
            try{
                StopWatch count=new StopWatch();
                long timer=count.getTime();
                long seconds=timer/1000;
                time = String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));//creating time
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        io=new Intent("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED");
        io.putExtra("countdown",time);
        sendBroadcast(io);// sending time value

        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}






@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Here the StopWatch class from`org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch`that can count timer from 0.
here it's my `MainActivity` implementation

```
Intent service=new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    startService(service);
    registerReceiver(updateGUI,new IntentFilter("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED"));

private BroadcastReceiver updateGUI=new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView countdown= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        countdown.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("countdown"));
    }

};
```

When i running my application, the counter is not running it stays in 00:00

Comment: also put your logcat, it will be helpful for us to know cause of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onCreate is only used to init things, use

`@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags , int startId){`

From the Docs:

#### onStartCommand

Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling 
 android.content.Context.startService, providing the arguments it supplied and a unique integer token 
 representing the start request. Do not call this method directly. 
For backwards compatibility, the default implementation calls onStart and returns either START_STICKY 
 or START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY. 
If you need your application to run on platform versions prior to API level 5, you can use the following 
 model to handle the older onStart callback in that case. The handleCommand method is implemented by you as appropriate

While as:

#### onCreate()

Called by the system when the service is first created. Do not call this method directly.
Overrides: onCreate() in Service

if all you want is to animate values in a text view over time, why not use a value animator? 
Example:

```
ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
                    animator.setObjectValues(0, percentage);
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            prog.setText("Profile Progress: "+String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue())+"%");
                        }
                    });
                    animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Integer>() {
                        public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
                            return Math.round((endValue - startValue) * fraction);
                        }
                    });
                    animator.setDuration(1500);
                    animator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks. it's worked but now the counter is not running it's stays in 00:00.

Comment: You can post that as a separate question :)

Comment: Is it only values you want to update in a text view? Isn't a service an overhead?

Comment: yes that is the only value i want update in textview

Answer (score 0):

While not immediately obvious, on Android a `Service` executes on the application's UI Thread by default.

To offload the work, a handy class `IntentService` exists in the toolkit for starting work that you want to execute in the background.

After having your class extend `IntentService`, override the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method and put your broadcast-generating code in there instead of in `onCreate`.

This will free up your UI thread to continue running as you expect.

(P.S. in your loop, you're never updating the value of `isScreenOn` so it will always remain the same!)

Comment: thanks @sddamico is any other way to do count up timer in android?

Comment: Yes, I would take a look at the `Handler` class which allows you to post `Runnable` actions with a desired ms delay. If you wanted to do something that ticks every second, you'd do: `handler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), 1000);`